# Typescript/React: Referring to other styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to reproduce this code from https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced in typescript.

```
const Link = styled.a`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: papayawhip;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

const Icon = styled.svg`
  flex: none;
  transition: fill 0.25s;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;

  ${Link}:hover & {
    fill: rebeccapurple;
  }
`;
```

What do I have to do for it to work in typescript?

Comment: they have already provided a how to in their document [styled component - typescript](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) . and please read how to ask a question on stack overflow and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to reference a component that I imported from another file instead of that component's styled counterpart. I mistakenly thought it was a typescript issue.